# Obtener registros diferentes entre 2 tablas SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente tabla articulos

```
cod_art desc_art prec_art
  123      art1    23.00
  234      art2    34.00
  567      art4    67.23
  317      art3    37.23
  567      art4    67.23
```

Y la tabla obsoletos

```
cod_art desc_art 
  123      art1   
  234      art2
```

Necesito obtener de la tabla articulos, aquellos que no se encuentren en la tabla obsoletos en este caso

```
 cod_art desc_art prec_art
  567      art4    67.23
  317      art3    37.23
  567      art4    67.23
```

Estoy usando la siguiente consulta

```
select cod_art,desc_art,prec_art 
       from articulos 
        except select cod_art 
                      from obsoletos
```

El problema que al usar except deben existir el mismo numero de columnas en la tabla uno y la tabla 2 por lo que solo me puede devolver cod_art y desc_art pero no puedo agregar prec_art por que no existe en obsoletos, que puedo hacer?

Answer (score 2):

Yo utilizo la sentencia "not in". Tengo entendido que no es la mejor opción para realizar esta tarea; pero no he encontrado la alternativa

```
select cod_art,desc_art,prec_art 
       from articulos 
       where cod_art not in (select cod_art from obsoletos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar left join con una condición where

```
select a.cod_art, a.desc_art, a.prec_art 
    from articulos a Left JOIN obsoletos o on a.cod_art = o.cod_art 
    where o.cod_art is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esto te servira.

SELECT
*
FROM (
SELECT cod_art, desc_art, prec_art
FROM articulos
) as sub
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
cod_art, desc_art
FROM obsoletos
) as sub2 ON sub.cod_art = sub2.cod_art